# Get dimension of element using Refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem that I'm stuck with some function that can get dimensions of some element. I'm working on project like Tabs and I want to 'border-bottom' the element that is active and make it nicely. So, I need to get width and left properties of each Tab. But Idk how to do it.
Here is the my piece of code:

```
        const Tabs = ({renderTab, options, value}) => {   
        // option is the array that contains info about each Tab
        // value is a state  and need I to compare this value to change Tab etc
        
            const [sliderInfo, setSliderInfo] = useState({width: 0, left: 0});
        
            const currentTab = options.findIndex((tab) => tab.value === value );  
            
            const tabsRef = options.map(() => {
                return useRef(null);
            });
            
            useEffect(() => {
                // I tried to something like that, but it didnt work
                setSliderWidth({
                    width: tabsRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width ,
                    left: tabsRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().left
                });
        
            }, [tabsRef]);
    
            return (
    
                <StyledTabsContainer>
                 {options.map((tab, i) => {  
                    return (
                        <div key={i}  className='wrapper'  ref={tabsRef[i]}  value={value} >
                            { renderTab(tab) }
                           
                        </div>            
                    )
                 })
                 }
                 <TabSlider width={sliderInfo.width} left={sliderInfo.left}></TabSlider>  
                
                </StyledTabsContainer>
        )
}
```

I will be very grateful if you can help me somehow!)

Comment: also `tabsRef ` is an array so `tabsRef.current` will never works should be something like `tabsRef[i].current`

Comment: It is not quite clear **what exactly** is it you're trying to achieve, but sounds, like you should be able to do that with CSS (or CSS-in-JS, for that matter).

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I want to get dimension of each element from array (left and width) and further with this information I will move something like border-bottom to active tab. The problem is how to get this measures (I tried to do it in useEffect)

Comment: My point was that you, likely, **don't need to get dimensions of your tabs** and there's a simpler way to arrange elements on the page in desired way or style your active tab accordingly or whatever is that you meant by *'..move something like border-bottom..'*.